# CMD - Setting a string in a variable to some other variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set

So what I'm trying to do is this:

I have a variable `%input%`,
let's say it's defined as `NAME`.

```
set input=NAME

set /p what="NAME: "
set %input%=%what%
```

I don't want to set `%input%` to be equal to `%what%`, I want to set `NAME` to be equal to `%what%`.

HOW do I do that??? (Because this way it's not working it says `ECHO is off.` when I try to `echo %NAME%`

Comment: You split it between two variables. `set x=%Var1` and `set y=var2%`.  To use `%x%%y%`.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible, the code works as it is! What did you enter? Do you have this code portion in a parenthesised block of code, together with `echo %NAME%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me!

```
Set input=NAME

Set /P what="NAME: "
Set %input%=%what%

Echo( %%input%%=%input% %%what%%=%what% %%NAME%%=%NAME%
Pause
```